# hashFiles in github action displays incorrect hash

Tags: hash, github-actions

I am running the following code in github actions

```
- name: Verify Workflow integrity
  run: |
        echo "some text" > test/apps/test/test.yml
        cat test/apps/test/test.yml
        
        echo "${{ hashFiles('test/apps/test/*.yml') }}"

        echo "alter text" > test/apps/test/test.yml
        cat test/apps/test/test.yml
        echo "${{ hashFiles('test/apps/test/*.yml') }}"
```

It produces the following output

```
| some text
| e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
| alter text
| e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Since the text in the file has changed, I am expecting a different hash. However, it produces the same hash. Am I missing something?

basically, I want to find the hash of all the files in `test/apps/test` directory

Answer (score 3):

The whole "script" in your `run` section is executed at once. Before execution, the "script" is being evaluated and all variables and/or function calls are resolved.

So before the "script" is being executed, `hashFiles('test/apps/test/*.yml')` is being evaluated (twice) with the result being `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`. Then the following resolved version of your "script" is being executed:

```
            echo "some text" > test/apps/test/test.yml
            cat test/apps/test/test.yml
            
            echo "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
    
            echo "alter text" > test/apps/test/test.yml
            cat test/apps/test/test.yml
            echo "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
```

So everything that happens in that script is not being considered, because all `hashFiles()` calls are resolved before everything is being executed.

A solution would be to split things up in multiple `run`s:

```yaml
    - name: Verify Workflow integrity
      run: |
            echo "some text" > test/apps/test/test.yml
            cat test/apps/test/test.yml
    - run: echo "${{ hashFiles('test/apps/test/*.yml') }}"
    - run: |
            echo "alter text" > test/apps/test/test.yml
            cat test/apps/test/test.yml
    - run: echo "${{ hashFiles('test/apps/test/*.yml') }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try the same test with the exact name file instead of a wildcard:

```bash
 echo "${{ hashFiles('test/apps/test/test.yml') }}"
```

(There was an [issue on `hashfiles` with `actions/runner`](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/319), but it is [supposed to be fixed](https://github.com/actions/runner/pull/268))

Second, try with double-quotes instead of single quotes (strong quotes) in order to make sure the '*' wildcard is interpreted by the shell.

```bash
 echo "${{ hashFiles("test/apps/test/*.yml") }}"
```